what does _forceClearCache in fabricjs do?
there is an called _forceClearCache in fabricjs. what does it mean, there is no definition or description about it.
Actually i try to chnage a font in textbox, the width and height were'nt chnaging. But if i change the _forceClearCache to true then the textbox dimension were working properly.
Version 5.2.4
My main concern is should i depend on that attribute or not?
